# amdgpu-install на Kubuntu 22.10

Tags: ubuntu, amd, kubuntu

Свежепоставленная Kubuntu 22.10, обновленная после установки. Хардварно установлена видеокарточка AMD. На Linux Mint проблем с установкой amdgpu-install (тул от AMD) не было, а тут случилось:

```
Следующие пакеты имеют неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 libwayland-amdgpu-client0 : Зависит: libffi7 (>= 3.3~20180313) но он не может быть установлен
 libwayland-amdgpu-client0:i386 : Зависит: libffi7:i386 (>= 3.3~20180313) но он не может быть установлен
 libwayland-amdgpu-server0 : Зависит: libffi7 (>= 3.3~20180313) но он не может быть установлен
 libwayland-amdgpu-server0:i386 : Зависит: libffi7:i386 (>= 3.3~20180313) но он не может быть установлен
 rocm-llvm : Зависит: python но он не может быть установлен
             Зависит: libstdc++-5-dev но он не может быть установлен или
                             libstdc++-7-dev но он не может быть установлен
             Зависит: libgcc-5-dev но он не может быть установлен или
                             libgcc-7-dev но он не может быть установлен
             Рекомендует: gcc-multilib но он не будет установлен
             Рекомендует: g++-multilib но он не будет установлен
 xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu : Зависит: xorg-video-abi-24 но он не может быть установлен
E: Невозможно исправить ошибки: у вас зафиксированы сломанные пакеты.
```

Какие-то драйвера AMD конечно в ядре ОС есть, но с ними далеко не тот полет: Xonotic (а-ля Quake) лагает на GPU 8GB / RAM 32GB...

Answer (score 1):

Нашел подсказку на форуме AMD. Экзотично почему стоковый пакет не работает, но, к счастью, решение найдено: https://community.amd.com/t5/drivers-software/ubuntu-22-04-amp-driver-amdgpu-install-22-10-2-50102-1-all-deb/m-p/549949/highlight/true#M161875. Подсказка в том, чтобы вручную смотреть предыдущие релизы в репозитории AMD. На момент ответа, ставить нужно вот этот пакет: https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu-install/5.4.2/ubuntu/jammy/